# Why can't I boot Antergos anymore after I booted Windows? (no normal dualboot)

Tags: linux, windows, boot, multi-boot, arch-linux

This is not a normal dual boot question.

**my setup:**

I have two SSDs, both are plugged in with a SATA data cable to my motherboard. The power cables however, are physically interupted with two switches. If the switches are turned off my MB cant see the SSDs. I only ever have one switch activated at a time so both operating Systems never get to know about the existance of each other.

**my issue:**

The first SSD contains a fresh installation of Windows 10. Works perfectly fine.
On the second SSD I installed Antergos and it also works (temporarily).

Now I do this:

1. shutdown Antergos
2. toggle both switches (Antergos off, Windows on)
3. boot into windows and shutdown
4. toggle both switches again (Antergos on, Windows off)
5. **Antergos doesn't boot anymore**

Windows continues to work perfectly fine.
I tried it with different Linux Distributions (always latest version):

- Antergos - doesn't work
- Voidlinux - doesn't work
- Ubuntu - works